# Firebase Authentication Error android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting a error like:

```
Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/
```

when I'm calling:

```
Firebase authenticateUser = new Firebase(ReferenceUrl.FIREBASE_CHAT_URL); // Get app main firebase url
                authenticateUser.authWithPassword(userName, passWord, authResultHandler);
```

I have created a project in Firebase and added the JSON file in app module and added the
compile `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0`
 library also please need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below method authenticate firebase sign in:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //display some message here
                        Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Successfully Signed In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        //display some message here
                        Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Signed In Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Firebase authenticateUser = new Firebase(ReferenceUrl.FIREBASE_CHAT_URL); // Get app main firebase url
                authenticateUser.authWithPassword(userName, passWord, authResultHandler); this method

Comment: @KunalDudka After using the method given by Amrut Bidri you need to check auth state to check if user signed in or not. If user signed in correctly then authstate will change. check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/. By the way I am seeing your authentication method first time, will you please point me a reference towards it in docs?